# MATLAB - updating the color of a surface plot with a callback

Tags: matlab

I want to simply change a surface plots Cdata with a callback.

```
cyl = surf(X_Length,Y_Circle,Z_Circle,'Cdata',map100);
```

I'm trying this

```
cyl.Cdata = map200;
```

but it won't work. Anyone know the proper way to do it?

this is the entire code.
I first create the cylinder.

```
map100 = getCylinderHeatMap(filename);

[X_Length,Y_Circle,Z_Circle,map100] = createSurfCylinderInitial(map100);
cyl = surf(X_Length,Y_Circle,Z_Circle,'Cdata',map100);
splitFileName = strsplit(string(T{1,1}),'.');

title(compose("3D Cylinder Heatmap Plot" + "\n" + "Time: " + splitFileName{1,1}));
zlabel("Z-Position");
ylabel("Y-Position");
xlabel("X-Length(Cm)");
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse')
colormap(myHeatMap);
colorbar;
shading interp

Maximum_Value = 450;
Minimum_Value = 50;
caxis([Minimum_Value Maximum_Value]);
```

In the callback i then update the colors.

```
function []= sliderCallback(b,T,myHeatMap,cyl)
value = round(b.Value);

%Testing lines load your matrix%
filename = strcat('\Users\Ali\Desktop\Documents\DataVis\Projekt\data\day\', string(T{value,1}));
map100 = getCylinderHeatMap(filename);
splitFileName = strsplit(string(T{value,1}),'.');

map100 = createSurfCylinderMapOnly(map100);
%surf(X_Length,Y_Circle,Z_Circle,'Cdata',map100);
cyl.CData = map100;

title(compose("3D Cylinder Heatmap Plot" + "\n" + "Time: " + splitFileName{1,1}));
zlabel("Z-Position");
ylabel("Y-Position");
xlabel("X-Length(Cm)");
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse');
colormap(myHeatMap);
colorbar;
shading interp
% 
Maximum_Value = 450;
Minimum_Value = 50;
caxis([Minimum_Value Maximum_Value]);
end
```

Yet nothing happens when i press the callback.
i think i need to some how redraw the cylinder but that was what i was trying to avoid in the first place to save computing power. and to just update the colormap.

Comment: That should work properly as long as the `Cdata` is within the correct range and the correct size. `Cdata` must be the same size as `map100` was.

Comment: What is “it won’t work”? Does it give an error message? Does it blank your screen? Does it just not have any effect at all? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `Cdata` has the same height and width as the old map data (`map100` dimensions = `map200` dimensions) the colour data should be replaced without any issues. Here I created a random `Cdata` colour map but of course, this array can be set to any `uint8` or `double` values you'd like. I'd suggest ensuring that `Cdata` is defined within your callback function before using it.

```
cyl = surf(X_Length,Y_Circle,Z_Circle,'Cdata',map100);
shading interp 

%Setting the surf to new test data%
[mapHeight,mapWidth] = size(map100);
map200 = rand(mapHeight,mapWidth);
cyl.CData = map200;
```

Comment: i think i need to redraw the cylinder after the new map data. 
Any ide on how to do that ?

Comment: Please don’t post code as comments, instead, update your question to further clarify it.

Comment: @Mr.Gomer I'm confused are you simply trying to redraw on a specific axis?